# Assign movie symbol to class error , cannot export in .mov in Flash CC?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash

Please kindly help me otherwise my 8 hour hard work of animation would be lost.

So I manually create a movie symbol in my Flash Main Timeline, it has an actionscript code in it like:

```
stop();
if(MovieClip(root).currentFrame<MovieClip(root).totalFrames){
 MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}
```

Converting it into a .mov file would not play the movie symbol (with its actionscript code like above).So I manually go and assign this movie symbol a class (Right-Click -> Properties ->Advanced ->Class Name)

After clickikng OK, it displays me an error saying "A definition for this class could not be found in the classpath, so one will be automatically generated in the SWF file upon export.

I right-clickthe name->Edit Class. Opens up with an empty constructor, but whwre is the animation code (like the 20 frames in this movie symbol)?

How do I export the .mov file so it plays the movie symbols (multiple instances of the movie symbol as well)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A definition for this class could not be found in the classpath, so one will be automatically generated in the SWF file upon export" -- I would not worry about this. It is simply saying that an actual class file does not exist.

Also, that as3 code will not execute on movie export. It is dependent on the animation playing in real time.

I would recommend removing this code, creating a keyframe on the very last frame, and in that frame inserting a stop();

Your frames will play all the way through until the last (stop) frame.